# Symfony 1.4 and Nginx with sfDoctrineGuardPlugin configuration issue

Tags: php, symfony1, nginx, symfony-1.4

Trying to install Symfony 1.4.11 application on Ubutnu Server + Nginx + php-fpm

Nginx configuration was applied from here: http://wiki.nginx.org/Symfony
See section: "Secure Symfony 1.4 config generalized from a production system & tested"

Public part of application works great, but when it comes to login - I get an error message:

"
**Oops! Page Not Found
The server returned a 404 response.**
"

In nginx error log I can see:

" **Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/backend_dev.php/login" (/)** "

The "**sfDoctrineGuardPlugin**" is used for authentication and can see all routes configured under:

```
$ php symfony app:routes backend
...
sf_guard_signout               ANY    /logout
sf_guard_signin                ANY    /login
...
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following configuration worked for me:

```
location ~ \.php($|/) {
    set  $script     $uri;
    set  $path_info  "";

    if ($uri ~ "^(.+\.php)(/.*)") {
        set  $script     $1;
        set  $path_info  $2;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$script;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $script;
}
```

Comment: So you solved your problem just 13 minutes after posted your question? .. uh

Comment: well, I Googled the web during 3 hours, and was in despair when posting the question here and then a friend of mine helped to resolve the issues. So I decided that this can be useful for community in case someone will have the same problem - when combination of configs from nginx official website and sfDoctrineGuardPlugin is not working.

Comment: Asking something interesting and including a reply right along is encouraged in Stack Overflow. You don't have to explain. By the way, your answer worked for me. Thanks!